# matplotlibrc rcParams modified for Jupyter inline plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

I have seen this question come up a couple of times, but I think this information changes as jupyter/ipython get updated.  I am currently running python 3.5, jupyter (latest) and matplotlib 2.0.
The `%matplotlib inline` plots have custom properties that are set after the matplotlibrc file is imported.  The most annoying of these is that the `figure.facecolor` property is set to be transparent which wreaks havoc when copy/pasting plots so I have to reset this property in the notebook.  I cannot seem to find where this property is changed, or if it is possible to create a configuration profile somewhere to change these special `inline` plot settings

My question is, is it possible to change these settings, and if so, how would I do that?

Comment: So the question is how to avoid typing `plt.rcParams["figure.facecolor"] = "white"` at the top of your notebook every time. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of the rcParameters are set specifically for the `inline` backend. Those are

```
{'figure.figsize': (6.0,4.0),  
 'figure.facecolor': (1,1,1,0), # play nicely with white background in the Qt and notebook
 'figure.edgecolor': (1,1,1,0),      
 'font.size': 10, # 12pt labels get cutoff on 6x4 logplots, so use 10pt.
 'figure.dpi': 72, # 72 dpi matches SVG/qtconsole
 'figure.subplot.bottom' : .125 # 10pt still needs a little more room on the xlabel
  }
```

And the place where they reside is the [`ipykernel/pylab/config.py`](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/master/ipykernel/pylab/config.py#L47) file.
This file can be edited to obtain the desired behaviour, e.g. by changing the facecolor to `'figure.facecolor': (1,1,1,1)` (no transparency).

Another option is the following:

The rcParameters are defined as part of the `InlineBackend` class, specifically the `InlineBackend.rc` attribute which is a `traitlets.Dict` object.

Those can be changed using the [ipython configuration system](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/config.html) as follows.

From the command line type `ipython profile create` which will generate the default configuration files in `~/.ipython`.  In the main configuration file `~/.ipython/ipython_config.py` include the line:

```
c.InlineBackend.rc.update({"figure.facecolor": "white"})
```

Comment: is there an ipython command to set/force matplotlib to use its default theme?

Comment: @steven At runtime you can call `plt.rcdefaults()`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm actually asking something like an ipython command without importing matplotlib. is there any? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7114

Comment: @steven Why not change the `ipython_config.py` as shown in the answer?

Comment: but what command should I include? just add `plt.rcdefaults()` ?

Comment: Actually, it's rather `c.InlineBackend.rc.update(matplotlib.rcParamsDefault)`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer was correct at the time. Recent update: The inline-specific backend will no longer override Matplotlib's defaults, see [this commit](https://github.com/ipython/matplotlib-inline/commit/a433a899280c9cf801ccb5eb99faa1e15fc8a459) from 12th of May 2022.

Before this recent change, the dict with the override values had moved to
[matplotlib-inline/matplotlib_inline/config.py](https://github.com/ipython/matplotlib-inline/blob/master/matplotlib_inline/config.py)