# How to increase the arrow size of axis_artist in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I play around with the example from [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/demo_axisline_style.html). 
[image]

I want to increase the size of the arrows at the ends of x-axis and y-axis. I found [this](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/api/axis_artist_api.html#mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axis_artist.AxisArtist.set_axisline_style):

> set_arrowstyle(“->,size=1.5”) set_arrowstyle(“->”, size=1.5)

So next I tried:

```
ax.axis["xzero"].set_axisline_style("->",  size=5)
```

But it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes with the use of a jupyter notebook and its inline backend. So you will get the correct output if using the `%matplotlib notebook` backend. (You need to restart the kernel for that.)

```
%matplotlib notebook
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import SubplotZero
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
    # adds arrows at the ends of each axis
    ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>", size=5)

    # adds X and Y-axis from the origin
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
    # hides borders
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

x = np.linspace(-0.5, 1., 100)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x*np.pi))

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want /need to use the `%matplotlib inline` backend, you may need to revert some of the settings, such that the arrows are not cropped from the figure.

1. The default setting for creating the png figure is the use of the `bbox_inches="tight"` option. This can be reverted via

   ```
   %config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}
   ```
2. The default figure size, dpi and subplot parameters [are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656668/matplotlibrc-rcparams-modified-for-jupyter-inline-plots). Reverting those can be done via

   ```
   plt.rcdefaults()
   ```

Due to [a bug](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3385) in Iypthon the rcParameters should not be set in the first cell of the notebook.

Hence

```
# Cell 1

%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}

# Cell 2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults() 
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import SubplotZero
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(1)

ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
    # adds arrows at the ends of each axis
    ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>", size=5)

    # adds X and Y-axis from the origin
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
    # hides borders
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

x = np.linspace(-0.5, 1., 100)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x*np.pi))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can the arrow color be changed?

Comment: Yes, `ax.axis[direction].line.set_facecolor("red")`

Answer (score 1):

The `size` parameter has to be within the quotes. You have passed it outside the quotes after a comma. Use the following

```
ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>, size=4")
```

[image]

Complete code from the [official website](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/demo_axisline_style.html)

```
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import SubplotZero
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if 1:
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
    fig.add_subplot(ax)

    for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
        # adds arrows at the ends of each axis
        ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>, size=4") # <--- modified here

        # adds X and Y-axis from the origin
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

    for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
        # hides borders
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

    x = np.linspace(-0.5, 1., 100)
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x*np.pi))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: It should work outside the quotes as well. In which version does it not work as expected?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest '2.0.2'

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Oh yes, you are right. I am on 2.2.2. Works both ways for me

Comment: Mhh, even in 2.0.2 I cannot reproduce this, meaning, both notations are working fine in 2.0.2 as well.

Comment: @Roma You are not showing a runnable code. I suspect you have something else in your code which prevents this from working.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I updated so now I have the same problem https://gist.github.com/kenenbek/c373856682bfe42ea5859307ceb3c44f

Comment: Yep, it's a problem only occuring in jupyter notebook with the inline backend. See my answer.